Adding ExoPlayer video to Recycler View's 0th position gives flickering
I am adding a video to 0th(or previous) position, when a current video started to play but when the item is added to 0th position its giving me flickering.
Issue video screen grab

Below is the code I am using to add item to 0th(or previous) position
mVideoList.add(0, item);
notifyItemInserted(0);

Also, if a video is added to the next position its not flickering.

So is it advisable to add video to the 0th(or previous) position as
the reels section of Youtube and Instagram don't have this feature.

Edit #1
Initialisation of Exo Player, this code is inside the Adapter
holder.mPlayerView.setPlayer(holder.player);
holder.mPlayerControllerView.setPlayer(holder.player);

MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(video.getVideourl()));
DataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
DefaultDataSource.Factory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(mContext, httpDataSourceFactory);

CacheDataSource.Factory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSource.Factory().setCache(simpleCache).setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(defaultDataSourceFactory).setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);

ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
holder.player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
holder.player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
holder.player.setRepeatMode(ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
holder.player.prepare();

And inside the onViewAttachedToWindow I am playing/pausing the video on the basis of current position.
Any help is appreciated.

The question actually lacks some more information. Can you comment on how you're initialising your ExoPlayer?

@gtxtreme added the asked details

Hmm, looks like onBindViewHolder, is a little heavy, could you try moving the common logic out, and see if the flicker goes away?

@gtxtreme Still the same issue appears, though if I play my first video its working good with no flickering, if a video is added to the previous position flickering only happens there

And what's the actual use case of adding to the previous position?

@gtxtreme When the current video is in front, an API is getting consumed, which gives us previous and next video if available.
So if both are available then we are adding to previous and next position
Only issue is while adding to the previous position

Tried this?

@RakshitNawani for me changing app:surface_type="texture_view" fixed the issue.

No help with the code mentioned, issue still persist
The main issue is adding video to the previous position.

@RakshitNawani Seems like your Adapter is getting started 2 times. Check the progress bar at the bottom of the player.

@BobSmith If I comment out the code of adding video to the previous position then the flickering is not happening, but if the code is present then this flickering is happening.
All in all the issue looks like to be in adding the video to the previous position

When you add a new video to the beginning of the list (mVideoList.add(0, item)) and notify the adapter (notifyItemInserted(0)), the view for the new video position might not be fully inflated and ready yet. By immediately setting the player and preparing the media source for the new view holder (holder), you might be triggering operations on an uninitialized view, leads to flickering.
